# How to remove elements which i find with find() jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an element in which i want to find a specific class and remove those class.

example

```
editingElm = `<p><span class="editing-target">hello</span><span class="editing-target">Welcome to this virtual world</span></p>`

 let elements = editingElm.find('.editing-target');// elements= [span,span] with the class
    editingElm.removeClass('editing-target');
```

How can i loop over the elements array and remove those classes i found?

Comment: You can't do `editingElm.find('.editing-target')` since based on your code, it's a string. you have to do `$(editingElm).find('.editing-target')` and then you can do `editingElm = $(editingElm).find('.editing-target').removeClass("editing-target")`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen okay will try this. but i still have to loop over it right?

Comment: You do not need to loop. `.find('.editing-target').removeClass("editing-target")` this will remove the class from all elements found by your `.find()`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Thanks for the explanation and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove class from `elements` instead of editingElm

```js
editingElm = `<p><span class="editing-target">hello</span><span class="editing-target">Welcome to this virtual world</span></p>`

let elements = editingElm.find('.editing-target');// elements= [span,span] with the class

elements.removeClass('editing-target');
```